# complex integral involving $e^z$ over unit $2$ circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am asked to evaluate

$$\int_{\vert z \vert = 2}\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}dz.$$

By partial fractions I found

$$\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2e}\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{e}{2}\frac{1}{z-1}.$$

So is the answer just

$$\pi i (\frac{e^2-1}{e}).$$

Is this correct?

Comment: what happened to $\mathrm{e}^z$ in the partial fractional decomposition?

Comment: did I decompose it incorrectly? @JonasLenz

Comment: well, the right hand side has no exponential in $z$. I would just decompose $\frac{1}{z^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z-1}$ and then multiply with the exponential. Then you can apply the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: I got the same result above though.. @JonasLenz

Comment: you have an exponential in the denominator though, give me a few moments and I will post a corrected calculation. Ah, I think your previous result was corrected, but in the calculations something seems to have gone wrong.

Comment: I agree with your answer but not with your partial fractions. You can also use the residue theorem if you wish (although that's basically partial fractions in disguise). Maybe prettier to put $2\pi i\cdot\sinh(1)$

Comment: You got the right answer because ultimately you did the right thing. But you did it at the wrong time and wrote something down that was non-sensical as a result. $$\frac{e^z}{z^2-1} = \frac {e^z}2\left(\frac 1{z-1} -\frac1{z+1}\right)$$ You only get to replace $e^z$ with $e^1$ and $e^{-1}$ when you integrate.